# How to use pipes(ioredirection) in Dockerfile RUN?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Following line in Dockerfile doesn't work:

```
RUN git archive master | tar -x -C /path
```

Error message:

```
fatal: Not a valid object name
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: How about the following variation: `git archive master | tar xf - -C /path`? And if that fails, can you verify that `git archive` actually works the way you expect by something like `git archive master --output=/tmp/path.tar`?

Comment: I tried VonC's solutions, still not able to use pipes in Dockerfile RUN. Looks like Dockerfile is not doing well on this. Using git archive --output to a tar file, and then `tar -xf /path/to/file.tar -C /path/to/extract` is a work around to this issue.

Comment: I'll convert my comment to an answer - please mark as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about the following variation: `git archive master | tar xf - -C /path`?

Answer (score 25):

You can try a `sh -c` command

```
RUN sh -c 'git archive master | tar -x -C /path'
```

If not, you can include that command in a script, COPY the script and RUN it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is actually with your git repository (or the directory your `RUN` is executing in):

```
fatal: Not a valid object name
```

This error is coming from git and suggests that there's no branch named `master`.

Comment: Yes. It's true. I didn't clone the git repo into a right folder. I fixed it, but the Pipes not working issue is still existing.