# Docker postgresql and postgis derived from image kartoza/postgis impossible to connect

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile, postgis

I created a dockerfile in order to make my `kartoza/postgis` image installation custom. My dockerfile should copy geotif images to a folder in the container and then run a combando of the `raster2pgsql` application in a pipe with the command `PGPASSWORD=password psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U admin -d elevation` ossia:

```
RUN sh -c raster2pgsql -s 4326 -C -F -I -t 100x100 /var/dem/w*.tif public.italy | PGPASSWORD=password psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U admin -d elevation
```

At this point I get the following error message:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker-compose.exe -f G:\spring-boot-elevation-finder\elevation-finder\docker-compose.yaml -p elevation-finder up -d
2023/07/04 20:58:56 http2: server: error reading preface from client //./pipe/docker_engine: file has already been closed
[+] Building 1.3s (8/8) FINISHED
 => [postgis internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [postgis internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.14kB                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [postgis internal] load metadata for docker.io/kartoza/postgis:latest                                                                              0.6s
 => [postgis internal] load build context                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 105B                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [postgis 1/3] FROM docker.io/kartoza/postgis@sha256:1360f5d3dcb2de05e8f6ced767e26a5f29344876a9ef119f1a3a69c9583eceda                               0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/kartoza/postgis@sha256:1360f5d3dcb2de05e8f6ced767e26a5f29344876a9ef119f1a3a69c9583eceda                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [postgis 2/3] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gdal-bin postgis nano  && apt-get clean   && apt-get -y autoremove   && rm -rf /var  0.0s
 => CACHED [postgis 3/3] COPY ./dem/* /var/dem/                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [postgis] exporting to image                                                                                                                       0.6s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                0.6s
 => => writing image sha256:17f8d7a48a38c7d375847f9d79c50c7a065f76ecdb306b2f2097e31b0231724a                                                           0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/elevation-finder-postgis                                                                                            0.0s
[+] Running 1/1
[+] Running 3/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
 âœ” Network elevation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9s  Container cloudbeaver_container           Creating                                                                                                  0.0s 
[+] Running 1/4cloudbeaver_container           Created                                                                                                   0.1
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 1/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 2/4evation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
 âœ” Network elevation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 2/4oudbeaver_container           Starting                                                                                                  2.5s 
 âœ” Network elevation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9
[+] Running 4/4admin4_container              Starting                                                                                                  2.5s 
 âœ” Network elevation-finder_postgis_network  Created                                                                                                   0.9s  Container pgadmin4_container              Starting                                                                                                  2.6s 
 âœ” Container cloudbeaver_container           Started                                                                                                   2.6s  Container pgadmin4_container              Starting                                                                                                  2.7s 
 âœ” Container postgis                         Started                                                                                                   2.7s 
 âœ” Container pgadmin4_container              Started                                                                                                   2.8s 
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker-compose.exe -f G:\spring-boot-elevation-finder\elevation-finder\docker-compose.yaml -p elevation-finder up -d

[+] Building 8.2s (8/8) FINISHED
 => [postgis internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                              0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [postgis internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                           0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.14kB                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [postgis internal] load metadata for docker.io/kartoza/postgis:latest                                                                              1.6s
 => [postgis 1/4] FROM docker.io/kartoza/postgis@sha256:1360f5d3dcb2de05e8f6ced767e26a5f29344876a9ef119f1a3a69c9583eceda                               0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/kartoza/postgis@sha256:1360f5d3dcb2de05e8f6ced767e26a5f29344876a9ef119f1a3a69c9583eceda                                       0.0s
 => [postgis internal] load build context                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 105B                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [postgis 2/4] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gdal-bin postgis nano  && apt-get clean   && apt-get -y autoremove   && rm -rf /var  0.0s
 => CACHED [postgis 3/4] COPY ./dem/* /var/dem/                                                                                                        0.0s
 => ERROR [postgis 4/4] RUN sh -c raster2pgsql -s 4326 -C -F -I -t 100x100 /var/dem/w*.tif public.italy | PGPASSWORD=password psql -h localhost -p 54  5.6s
------
 > [postgis 4/4] RUN sh -c raster2pgsql -s 4326 -C -F -I -t 100x100 /var/dem/w*.tif public.italy | PGPASSWORD=password psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U admin -d elevation:
#0 2.358 psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
#0 2.358        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
#0 2.358        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
#0 2.358 could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
#0 2.358        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
#0 2.358        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c sh -c raster2pgsql -s 4326 -C -F -I -t 100x100 /var/dem/w*.tif public.italy | PGPASSWORD=password psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U admin -d elevation" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2
`docker-compose` process finished with exit code 17
```

Docker-compose

```
version: "3.8"
#name: my-project-name


services:

  postgis:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    # image: kartoza/postgis:${POSTGIS_VERSION_TAG}
    container_name: postgis
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASS=${POSTGRES_PASS}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - ALLOW_IP_RANGE=${POSTGRES_ALLOW_IP_RANGE}
      - POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_EXTENSIONS=${POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_EXTENSIONS}
      - POSTGRES_DATA_VOLUME:${POSTGRES_DATA_VOLUME}
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - postgis-data:${POSTGRES_DATA_VOLUME}
    networks:
      - postgis_network

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:${PGADIM_VERION_TAG}
    container_name: ${PGADIM_CONTAINER_NAME}
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
      - PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE:${PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE}
    networks:
      - postgis_network
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:${PGADIM_DATA_VOLUME}
        #depends_on:
      #postgis:
      #condition: service_healthy

  cloudbeaver:
    image: dbeaver/cloudbeaver:23.1.0
    container_name: cloudbeaver_container
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8085:8978"
    volumes:
      - cloudbeaver-data:/opt/cloudbeaver/workspace
    networks:
      - postgis_network



volumes:
  postgis-data:
  pgadmin-data:
  cloudbeaver-data:

networks:
  postgis_network:
      driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM kartoza/postgis

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gdal-bin postgis nano\
  && apt-get clean \
  && apt-get -y autoremove \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY ./dem/* /var/dem/


RUN sh -c raster2pgsql -s 4326 -C -F -I -t 100x100 /var/dem/w*.tif public.italy | PGPASSWORD=password psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U admin -d elevation
```

.ENVI

```
POSTGIS_VERSION_TAG=15-3.3
POSTGRES_USER=admin
POSTGRES_PASS=password
POSTGRES_DB=elevation
POSTGRES_ALLOW_IP_RANGE=0.0.0.0/0
POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_EXTENSIONS=postgis,hstore,postgis_topology,postgis_raster,pgrouting
POSTGRES_DATA_VOLUME=/var/lib/postgresql


PGADIM_VERION_TAG=6.14
PGADIM_CONTAINER_NAME=pgadmin4_container
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@admin.com
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin
PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE=False
PGADMIN_PORT=5050
PGADIM_DATA_VOLUME=/var/lib/pgadmin
```

Comment: You're not going to be able to run `raster2pgsql` during the build process because at that point the postgres server isn't running. That's the sort of command you need to run **after** you've started a container from the image.

Comment: This seems fundamentally the same as [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76608386/dockerfile-run-a-psql-postgres-command-with-run); what is different?